# Not able to compile Maven project due to dependencies.dependency.version is missing

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

Why do I get an error when I try to clean and compile my Maven project from the root folder? I use the top level POM for defining dependencies in the dependencyManagement element. I want to use it in the library projects.

I have the following Maven project structure:

```
POM
    Library1
    POM
        Module1
        POM
        Module2
        POM
    Library2
        Module1
        POM
        Module2
        POM
```

From top level POM:

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

Library POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Are you missing the version  <version>3.0.2.Final</version> in library pom

Comment: @Makky No, obviously it was missing `<type>pom</type>`. Does that make sense? Probably because pom isn't default, so you need to specify that?

Comment: First of all, the indentation in your project structure listing doesn't make sense. I assume the error occurs when building the Library Project? What if you build it directly? How do you reference the top-level project?

Comment: @Arian I have one folder with POM and other Maven projects. These Maven projects have another POM and more Maven projects. They are only nested, and the relations between them is properly configured with module and parent elements. As I said, I have got it working by adding type element with pom.

Comment: In that case, answer the question so that others can find the solution easily

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add type element in the dependency.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```